# Paperjs 0.9.25 - item.setRampPoint is not a function

Tags: javascript, java, svg, paperjs

I have been using `paperjs` for a year now, without any issues. After a Chrome update `(Version 55.0.2883.87 m)` some production code that I hadn't touched for 2 months started failing with the `error: item.setRampPoint is not a function`:

`paper-full.js:13213 Uncaught TypeError: item.setRampPoint is not a function`

```
at offset (paper-full.js:13213)
at Object.<anonymous> (paper-full.js:13263)
at Object.forIn (paper-full.js:46)
at Function.each (paper-full.js:133)
at applyAttributes (paper-full.js:13260)
at importGroup (paper-full.js:12944)
at importSVG (paper-full.js:13324)
at Project.importSVG (paper-full.js:13356)
at drawAddLaneButtons (tlc.js:267)
at Path.window.drawTlcElements (tlc.js:62)
```

If I comment out the call to `setRamPoint` in the `paperjs` code it starts working again.

This happens when I try to load a SVG to the page, but, as I said before, it was working fine for a long time.

I am using version 0.9.25 of `paperjs`.

Any ideas?

Comment: It will help to clarify in what situation you are calling item.setRampPoint. Is setRampPoint a function you wrote? And, if you want to check something quickly, try setRampPoint(item).

Comment: Hi, @EvSunWoodard. I am not calling 'setRamPoint' this is a internal function of paperjs. The funny thing is that this code is used every single day for thousands of users and it just stopped working after this last Chrome update. Everything still fine on IE and Firefox.

Comment: What happens if you try the latest version of paper.js?

Comment: Hi @ChrisG. If I test it with the lastest version of paper.js I don't get the error anymore, but the SVGs I was loading on the canvas don't show anymore. I get a better result just commenting out the calling to setRamPoint in the line 13213 of the version 0.9.25.

Comment: For future reference it has been fixed by changing the headers of the SVG I was import and using the latest version of paperjs.

Comment: Could you please provide the SVG file that was causing this issue? I need to be able to reproduce it in order to say what's causing it. The issue for this problem is here: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1222

Comment: @NelsonLarios I'd be interested in seeing this SVG file that also causes issues on the latest version, and understand why the headers needed changing. Ideally this wouldn't be required.

Comment: @JürgLehni I will be on holidays for the next 10 days. I will make sure to post the code and the SVG file when I am back. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JürgLehni, it turns out that changing the headers was not necessary. Only updating to the newest version fixed the problem. Thanks, everybody!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had the same problem and updated to newly PaperJS version. It worked

Comment: Came here with the same problem and updating to PaperJS 0.10.2 (newest at the moment)  fixed it as well

Comment: How is the clone function not working? Could you report an issue over at https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/ ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If someone wants to avoid updating paperjs.

A simple *hack* could be :

```
if (!paper.Item.prototype.setRampPoint) {
     paper.Item.prototype.setRampPoint = function () {};
}
```

Doesn't seem to break anything.